# TMOD value for timer 1 in mode 0 in 8051 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, assembly, 8051

What will be result of this statement:

```
MOV TMOD,#00H
```

Will it set it to timer 0 in mode 0 or to timer 1 in mode 0?

Other statements like:

```
MOV TMOD,#01H ;----- sets timer 0 mode 1
MOV TMOD,#10H ;----- sets timer 1 mode 1
```

didn't create any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all of those statements modify BOTH timers:

```
MOV TMOD,#00H ; set timer 0 mode 0 AND timer1 mode 0
MOV TMOD,#01H ; set timer 0 mode 1 AND timer1 mode 0
MOV TMOD,#10H ; set timer 0 mode 0 AND timer1 mode 1
```

If you want to modify only one of the timers, you must do a read-modify-write, preserving the bits on the timer you're not changing.

For example, if you want to force Timer0 to mode 0 without changing anything else, you might do:

```
ANL TMOD,#FCh ; binary 11111100 -- bit mask with two LSBs cleared
```

Comment: And can you tell the command for setting timer 1 in mode 0 specifically?

Comment: You can't work it out from the information given so far? Look again at the definition of the TMOD register.

Comment: I got that. Thanks Dave.